Error when fetching FCM token: Invalid fetch response
I’m facing an issue retrieving the FCM token on iOS in my Flutter app, which blocks push notifications for iOS users.
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#getToken, errorOrNil => {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Invalid fetch response, expected 'token' or 'Error' key";
}
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:534:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:248:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      main (package:sjdvs/main.dart:77:19)
<asynchronous suspension>



**Same Error for Messaging#subscribeToTopic
FLTFirebaseMessaging: An error occurred while calling method Messaging#subscribeToTopic, errorOrNil => {
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Invalid fetch response, expected 'token' or 'Error' key"**;
}
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred.

I updated all Firebase dependencies, ran flutter clean, and reinstalled iOS pods with pod install --repo-update. I expected the app to retrieve the FCM token on iOS as it does on Android, but it returned an error indicating an "Invalid fetch response, expected 'token' or 'Error' key."
Environment:

Flutter Version: 3.22.1 (stable channel)

firebase_messaging: ^15.1.3

firebase_core: ^3.6.0

firebase_storage: ^12.3.4

cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4

iOS Deployment Target: iOS 14.0

Xcode Version: 15.4



I believe that this issue is only while running the app in a simulator.
To fix that, you should call APNSToken for iOS.
  (Platform.isAndroid
            ? FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()
            : FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken())

This should work in your case.
Note: To receive notifications, getToken() should be used.

It works, Thanks!
